# connect(mapStateToProps, { function }) isn't setting function to this.props - React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**I'm trying to call my API on componentDidMount in my Leads Component as follows:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getLeads } from "../../actions/leads";

export class Leads extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getLeads();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Leads List</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    leads: state.leadsReducer.leads
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getLeads })(Leads);
```

The problem is that the last line `connect()` function doesn't seem to be setting `getLeads` as a method for `this.props`.

When I log `this.props`, I get a empty `{}`.

**When I build and run the app, this is what I get in the console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getLeads is not a function
    at Leads.componentDidMount (Leads.js:42)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:17130)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18532)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:18744)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:20214)
    at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
    at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:20213)
```

**Here's my ../actions/leads.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_LEADS } from './types';


// GET LEADS
export const getLeads = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .get("/api/leads/")
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_LEADS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err =>console.log(err));
};
```

I know I'm missing something silly here, would be great to know what.

Comment: I don's see anything that's wrong with the code... If you create a small example on https://codesandbox.io and post it here I can try to help you..

Comment: can you try replacing your 2nd argument to connect function with mapDispatchToProps  as const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getLeads: () => dispatch(getLeads()),
 
  }
}

Comment: If you're using redux thunk, then you should just be able to do: `getLeads()` and not use `connect()` for the actions at all.

Comment: @Colin I'm using thunk. I tried to use the function directly, no luck with that as well.

Comment: @KaranGarg  No help with that.

Comment: @SakoBu I've put my project on [Github](https://github.com/justvidyadhar/lead-manager/tree/master/leadmanager/frontend/src) 

You can have a look at the structure and files. I'm working with React and Django in backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be exporting the class instead only export the connected instance otherwise if you use the class without the connect HOC wrapped you won't be seeing the props from redux store

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getLeads } from "../../actions/leads";

class Leads extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getLeads();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Leads List</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    leads: state.leadsReducer.leads
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getLeads })(Leads);
```

Now in order to use `Leads` component, you would import like as a default import like

```
import Leads from './path/to/Leads';
```

Comment: When I do that, It cannot find the Leads component in the other files where I import it.

Comment: Here's the entire file structure on [Github](https://github.com/justvidyadhar/lead-manager/tree/master/leadmanager/frontend/src)

Comment: Since the container is a default export, in order to import it, you must import leads kike `import  Leads from './Leads';`. I see that you were importing it as a named export `import { Leads } from './Leads';` in Dashboard.js which lead to the error you mentioned in your code since you were not using the connected instace